# How to change headline text when a drop down menu is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my WordPress site I am using jQuery to update the text inside a H2 header when options inside a drop down menu are selected.

The code below works perfectly here, but I cannot get it working on my live site.

Here is the working code that I am using:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#wpfs-plan--NjUyMTB").change(function() {
    var selectedValue = this.value;
    if (selectedValue == 'SEO_500_word_articles') {
      jQuery('#price_value').text('299');
    } else if (selectedValue == 'SEO_1000_word_articles') {
      jQuery('#price_value').text('598');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<h1 style="margin-bottom: 25px;">The price is: <span id="price_value">299</span></h1>

<select id="wpfs-plan--NjUyMTB" style="width: 200px;">
  <option value="SEO_500_word_articles">SEO 500 words $299</option>
  <option value="SEO_1000_word_articles">SEO 1000 words $598</option>
</select>
```

Note: I cannot change the HTML on the site because it loads via a plugin, I can only the JavaScript that interacts with the HTML.

Comment: It seems like the `jQuery` version.

Comment: I thought this also but I tested the exact same version of jQuery that WordPress is using inside JS Fiddle (importing via CDN) and it works fine in the fiddle. Tested both `1.12.4` and `1.4.1`.

Comment: can you use this url ? <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> and let me know, I guess this should fix your issue.

Comment: Inside a Fiddle? Here it is working fine https://jsfiddle.net/wyopsj0b/1/. I can't change the jQuery version in WordPress because it comes standard with `1.12.4`.

Comment: would you mind sharing the html tag till body?

Comment: Here you go: https://pastebin.com/WwBWeubP. You can also check it by visiting the site and then "view source".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210135/discussion-between-manjuboyz-and-tinytiger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select tag will not fire "change" event if its value is changed programmatically.

You have to use the widget that wraps the custom select.
With a bit of digging I found out that the custom select is created in the wpfs.js file at line 1598.

So if you do the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(() => {
  jQuery('#wpfs-plan--NjUyMTB').wpfsSelectmenu({
    change() {
      const selectedValue = this.value;
      if (selectedValue === 'SEO_500_word_articles') {
        jQuery('#price_value').text('299');
      } else if (selectedValue === 'SEO_1000_word_articles') {
        jQuery('#price_value').text('598');
      }
    },
  });
});
```

it will wrap the function to the widget and it will be called correctly.

Comment: Tried like this https://pastebin.com/ZYwSA85s and also without the docready wrapper like this https://pastebin.com/2Tj3Nex3

Comment: Weird... I tried it via console and it worked... Do you have a live version with this portion of code?

Comment: Ok got it working! I used your solution to get there, so update your asnwer with https://pastebin.com/AKX1MnvB and I'll make that one as solved

Comment: Great! Edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the value of selectedValue to  $( this).val()

Comment: I used this `var selectedValue = jQuery(this).val();` because WordPress need me to use `jQuery` and not `$` but it didnt work.